# Can someone please take a stab at fixing "Proof" tag Wiki?

Tags: discussion, editing

I just approved a new tag wiki for [proof](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof).

It is (IMHO) an overall good writeup content-wise, but I think is in need of major editing to tighten it up and fix the grammar a bit. I tried to take a stab at it and wasn't producing anything much better, so I'm posting this on Meta in hopes of someone with better editing skills giving it a shot.

You are welcome to post suggestions to improve as answers/comments to this Meta, but the main point of the post is to attract an attention of an editing volunteer since I really like the tag's contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've cleaned it up a wee bit. However, frankly I find myself doubting the entire concept of the tag. I don't really think anything can be conclusively "proven" about history; the best you can really come down with is what seems to be consensus opinion about events, or what seems very likely or unlikely.

If you don't believe me, go have a 10 minute conversation with a moon landing denier.

Comment: @TED - your last comment is an insidious attempt at nerd sniping.

Comment: @TED - [here](http://xkcd.com/356/) and [here](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php?title=356:_Nerd_Sniping)

Comment: As I was the very first author of the text, I can only say that this was my guessing, I haven't invented this tag and had no idea what it should be. I wanted to put just something that would be improved by somebody else. I believe it's better to encourage somebody to improve then have nothing, as it is more difficult to write a brand new text. Reading this discussion and history of changes for this tag I am glad I managed to make the community to write this together.

Comment: @Voitcus - Good job there. I'm also generally of the opinion that any wiki is better than no wiki. Its the tag itself I'm not so sure about.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to "clean it up"; I hope that I didn't make too drastic an alteration.  I think the existing tag was about logical proof, and I think that historical proof is a distinct concept.

I share the concern that "proof" may take us down a rabbit hole; this feels like a meta-tag.